# How to make a json of arrays

Tags: jquery, local-storage

What i am trying to do is trying to make a json with arrays of items in it and put them to localstorage. the code below is working but when i put first array in it goes in just fine but when the second array is inserted it become an index of the first array like an object that is not desired i want to keep them both as separate objects in the local storage (details is an array in the format given below). Any Help is much Appreciated Thanks.

```
details = [{"AmountRequested":"232323"},{"Status":"New"},{"DetailsID":"38"}]

        function PutToLocalStorage(details) {
        var a = [];

        console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
        if (localStorage.getItem("Details") === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("Details", JSON.stringify(details));
        }
        else {
            a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Details"));
            console.log(a);
            var detailsid = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < details.length; i++) {
                if (details[i].DetailsID != null) {
                    detailsid = details[i].DetailsID;
                }
            }

            a.push(details);
            localStorage.setItem('Details', JSON.stringify(a));}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getItem('Details')` yields `null`, you are currently putting only the `details` object into it.

In the `else` clause, you are using `getItem('Details')` and assign it to `a`, which I assume means you expect it to be an array, when in fact your first insert is an object.

It seems to me that you want to always use `a.push(details);` and store `a`, even on the first insert, so that you'll always be working with an array of items.

Comment: Thanks @David Hedlund That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep separate objects, push array of details initially. Modify code to -

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Details") === null) {
            localStorage.setItem("Details", JSON.stringify([details]));
}
```